# How to export the matrix pricing CSV from the App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

A few months ago, the complete pricing matrix could be downloaded in CSV from the App Store Connect with the list of all countries and tiers from this URL:

[https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/[APP_ID]/pricingMatrix](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/%5BAPP_ID%5D/pricingMatrix)

But unfortunately this URL stopped working and has been changed to this one:

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/pricingmatrix

With no CSV export button. Any idea?

Comment: This has caught me out as well - did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope. When Apple announces any change, I change it by hand. You may find this useful: https://github.com/danielblazquez/Pricing-matrix-AppStoreConnect